# How do i change element's name including number in xml using python?

Tags: python, xml-parsing

How do I change element's name including number in `xml` using python?

I've already known how to change name of element in `xml` using python but I want to know how to change name of element including numbers.

Below is example of xml.

```
<AAA>  <- this the first AAA under data>
    <CCC>
        <BBB>This</BBB>
    </CCC>
    <CCC>  
        <BBB>is</BBB>
    </CCC>
    <CCC>
        <BBB>test</BBB>
    </CCC>
</AAA> 

<AAA> <- this the second AAA under data>
    <CCC>
        <BBB>This is test</BBB>
    </CCC>
</AAA>

<AAA>
    <BBB>
        <CCC>This is test</CCC>
    </BBB>
</AAA>
```

I'm trying to change the `AAA` element name including number like as `AAA` to `AAA1` and `AAA` to `AAA2`.

The first `AAA` should be changed to `AAA1` and the second `AAA` to `AAA2` like below.

```
<AAA1>  <- this the first AAA under data>
    <CCC>
        <BBB>This</BBB>
    </CCC>
    <CCC>  
        <BBB>is</BBB>
    </CCC>
    <CCC>
        <BBB>test</BBB>
    </CCC>
</AAA1> 

<AAA2> <- this the second AAA under data>
    <CCC>
        <BBB>This is test</BBB>
    </CCC>
</AAA2>

<AAA3>
    <BBB>
        <CCC>This is test</CCC>
    </BBB>
</AAA3>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try as following, it will read `original.xml` and create `new.xml`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xmlParser
from xml import etree

with open("original.xml") as f:
    xmlDoc = xmlParser.fromstringlist(["<root>", f.read(), "</root>"])

for index,element in enumerate(xmlDoc.iter('AAA')):
    element.tag = 'AAA' + str(index+1)

# save to new xml file
with open('new.xml','ab') as f:
    out = list(xmlDoc)
    for item in out:
        f.write(etree.ElementTree.tostring(item))
```

Comment: Great! `Happy Coding`.

Comment: @student: How to do the same with minidom plz..?